# Build Sequence in postgres sql depending on the session

Tags: postgresql

In postgres sql, at the time of insert data from select to another table , I have to build a sequence depending upon the session, for every session sequence should have start from 1 and increment by one.
when new session inserted sequence should start from 1.

[image]

Comment: Please post the SQL query you use to "*insert data from select to another table*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate sequence on insert:

```
insert into mytable (session, sequence, ...)
values (1, (select count(*) + 1 from mytable where session = 1), ...)
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/84ad36/1).